# Breaking up a query and passing the results of one query to another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a query that seems to work, but it takes forever. I am thinking that if I break the query in two, and pass the result of the first query into the second, that it may be more efficient.

The idea is, that the table contains data for many symbols. Is there a way to query the table for only those symbols = 'AAPL' for example, and then pass that result set into the next query?

This is on SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
SELECT 
    T1.CompSymbol, 
    T1.TradeDate, 
    T1.Expiry, 
    MIN(T2.Expiry) AS 'FrontMonthContract' ,   
    MIN(T1.CompATMSynthStrike) AS 'CompATMSynthStrike',
    MIN(T1.CompATMSynthIV) AS 'CompATMSynthIV'   
FROM 
    BandHistory1M T1, BandHistory1M T2 
WHERE T1.TradeDate <= T2.Expiry AND T1.CompSymbol = 'AAPL'
GROUP BY T1.CompSymbol , T1.TradeDate, T1.Expiry
```

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace ConsoleGetFrontMonth
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dictionary<int, int> frontMonthContract = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            frontMonthContract.Add(4, 17);
            frontMonthContract.Add(5, 16);
            frontMonthContract.Add(6, 20);
            frontMonthContract.Add(7, 18);
            frontMonthContract.Add(8, 22);
            frontMonthContract.Add(9, 19);
            frontMonthContract.Add(10, 17);
            frontMonthContract.Add(11, 21);
            //frontMonthContract.Add(5, 16);
            //frontMonthContract.Add(5, 16);

            BandsEntities bandsContext = new BandsEntities();

            IQueryable<BandHistory1M> symbolQuery =
                from source in bandsContext.BandHistory1M
                where source.CompSymbol == "AAPL"
                select source;


            foreach (var Symbol in symbolQuery)
            {
                int dayExpires;
                if(false == frontMonthContract.TryGetValue(Symbol.TradeDate.Month, out dayExpires))
                    continue;

                if (Symbol.TradeDate.Month == Symbol.Expiry.Month)
                {
                    if (Symbol.TradeDate.Day < dayExpires)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", Symbol.CompSymbol, Symbol.TradeDate, Symbol.Expiry);
                    }
                }
                else if(1 == (Symbol.Expiry.Month - Symbol.TradeDate.Month))
                {
                    if(Symbol.TradeDate.Day > dayExpires)
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", Symbol.CompSymbol, Symbol.TradeDate, Symbol.Expiry);
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the query code. Also tag your question with the RDBMS you're using. In other news - splitting a query into smaller parts without further optimization won't net any benefits. It may actually worsen performance.

Comment: What are you trying to do with that query?

Comment: This is a pretty simple aggregate query. I don't think you can optimize the statement itself so you should look to create indexes. SSMS actually gives you pretty good hints this way - have you looked at the estimated/actual execution plans?

Comment: How does SSMS give these hints? I don't understand what you mean when you ask "have you looked at the estimated/actual execution plans?"

Comment: If you have DBA around, talk to them about it. Otherwise you have some reading to do: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510669.aspx

Comment: It is amazing to me that the C# code that I added above does EXACTLY what I want it to do (using LINQ to Entities), and the whole thing runs in about 1 minute instead of two weeks in pure SQL. Of course, I might be able to add a table that has the same effect on the C# Dictionary...

Comment: We would need your table & index definitions to be able to shed any real light on this.

Comment: Also, this looks like a "Triangular Join" problem (see here:http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/), which are notorious for being very hard to optimize in SQL, though easy to do in client code.

Answer (score 0):

Without the Table Defs I'm just guessing, but try it like this:

(oops, first one was bad ...)

or maybe even this:

```
SELECT 
    T1.CompSymbol, 
    T1.TradeDate, 
    T1.Expiry, 
    MIN(T2.Expiry) AS 'FrontMonthContract' ,   
    MIN(T1.CompATMSynthStrike) AS 'CompATMSynthStrike',
    MIN(T1.CompATMSynthIV) AS 'CompATMSynthIV'   
FROM BandHistory1M T1
JOIN BandHistory1M T2  ON T1.TradeDate <= T2.Expiry
GROUP BY T1.CompSymbol , T1.TradeDate, T1.Expiry
HAVING T1.CompSymbol = 'AAPL'
```

Uh, ... nope, I had it right in my comment above.  This is the notorious "running total" or "[triangular join](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/61539/)" problem.  It is easy to do in client code, but can only be done efficiently in TSQL with an extremely tricky (and unsupported) device called a pseudocusor or a "quirky update".